# Javascript button eventListener not showing data

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am building a sample application (Tennis Club Management)using javascript,html,css,bootstrap in which i have built login page and profile page .In profile page, i have built side bar with anchor tag links which opens the corresponding HTML page (for example : **managePlayers.html**).

**Now** the problem is in **managePlayers.html**, in this i have two buttons and added **eventListener** on the buttons, currently i want to log in the browser that button is clicked.
But the **eventListener** is not working.

**Below are the code files and screenshots**

**index.html(Login Page)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tennis Club Project</title>

    <!-- ADDING FONT AWESOME CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- ADDING STYLE.CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <img src="./lock.png" alt="lock" class="lock">

    <!-- ADDING "DIV" CONTAINER -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form class="login-form">
                <h5>TENNIS CLUB ADMIN LOGIN</h5>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email Address :</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control email" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                        placeholder="Enter Email ID">
                    <label class="labelemailerror"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password :</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
                    <label class="labelpassworderror"></label>
                </div>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary loginbtn">Log In</button>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label class="forgotpassword"><span>Forgot Password ?</span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label class="signup"><span>Sign Up</span></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP JS -->
    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    

    <!-- ADDING INDEX.JS -->
    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**index.js**

```
// --------------TESTING CODE FOR LOGIN PAGE LOGIN BUTTON CLICK----------------


var email, password;
document.querySelector(".loginbtn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    email = document.querySelector(".email").value;
    password = document.querySelector(".password").value;

    document.querySelector(".labelemailerror").innerHTML = "";
    document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "";

    // ------------TESTING CODE FOR CHECKING VALIDATION AND PRINTING ERROR ON LABELS IF ANY-------------

    if (email === "admin@wimbledon.com" && password === "rogerfederer") {
        console.log("Login successfull....");
        window.open("profile.html");
    }
    else if (email === "" && password === "") {

        document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "Email and Password cannot be blank"
    }
    else if (email === "") {

        document.querySelector(".labelemailerror").innerHTML = "Email cannot be blank";
    }
    else if (password === "") {

        document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "Password cannot be blank"
    }
    else {

        document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "Invalid Email or Password";
    }

    console.log(email, password);
    e.preventDefault();
});







/*

---------------------TESTING CODE FOR PROFILE HTML PAGE----------------------

*/

function init() {
    var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
    myDiv.className = "sidebar";

    document.body.appendChild(myDiv);



    var home = document.createElement("a");
    home.className = "active home";
    home.href = "profile.html";
    home.innerHTML = "Home";

    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(home);



    var managePlayers = document.createElement("a");
    managePlayers.className = "active managePlayers";
    managePlayers.href = "managePlayers.html";
    managePlayers.innerHTML = "Manage Players";

    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(managePlayers);



    var manageTournaments = document.createElement("a");
    manageTournaments.className = "active manageTournaments";
    manageTournaments.href = "manageTournaments.html";
    manageTournaments.innerHTML = "Manage Tournaments";

    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(manageTournaments);


    var manageMatches = document.createElement("a");
    manageMatches.className = "active manageMatches";
    manageMatches.href = "manageMatches.html";
    manageMatches.innerHTML = "Manage Matches";

    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(manageMatches);


    var manageTrainers = document.createElement("a");
    manageTrainers.className = "active manageTrainers";
    manageTrainers.href = "manageTrainers.html";
    manageTrainers.innerHTML = "Manage Trainers";

    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(manageTrainers);



    var manageFees = document.createElement("a");
    manageFees.className = "active manageFees";
    manageFees.href = "manageFees.html";
    manageFees.innerHTML = "Manage Fees";

    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(manageFees);



    var logout = document.createElement("a");
    logout.className = "active logout";
    logout.href = "index.html";
    logout.innerHTML = "Logout";

    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(logout);
}




//----------------------TESTING CODE FOR LOGOUT-----------------------

document.querySelector(".logout").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    window.open("index.html");
    e.preventDefault();
});




//-------------------TESTING CODE FOR DISPLAYING "SHOW PLAYERS TABLE" OF MANAGE PLAYERS HTML PAGE----------------

document.querySelector(".showplayers").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log("show players button clicked.......");
    e.preventDefault();
});


//--------------------TESTING CODE FOR "ADDING PLAYERS" OF MANAGE PLAYERS HTML PAGE-------------------------------

document.querySelector(".addplayers").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    console.log("add players button clicked......");
});
```

**The Problem(the eventListener for the buttons below are not firing up)**

```
//-------------------TESTING CODE FOR DISPLAYING "SHOW PLAYERS TABLE" OF MANAGE PLAYERS HTML PAGE----------------

document.querySelector(".showplayers").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log("show players button clicked.......");
    e.preventDefault();
});


//--------------------TESTING CODE FOR "ADDING PLAYERS" OF MANAGE PLAYERS HTML PAGE-------------------------------

document.querySelector(".addplayers").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    console.log("add players button clicked......");
});
```

**Screenshots**

**Login Page**

[image: Null error also occurs]

**Manage Players Page**

[image: Event is not firing up]

**Any solution please ?**

Comment: document.querySelector(".showplayers") your Html node does not exist in the DOM a the time you are attaching the listener to it, the problems is with your init function it should execute only after you profile page has completely loaded.

Answer (score 1):

When the login page is loaded `document.querySelector(".logout")` is null.

This happens because the code executes before the `init()` function is called.

Call `init` first:

```
init();

document.querySelector(".logout").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    window.open("index.html");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

When the manage players page is loaded `document.querySelector(".loginbtn")` is null.